# PHP echo not working even though variable is captured

Tags: php

I am trying to work with this script and get it to echo the results for a variable called bio. The code below does work and when I run `var_dump($result);` I do get the array from the test table that shows the bio variable data for that record. Oddly, I just can't get that variable to echo using the code below. What am I missing here?

```
<?php
    include "ASEngine/AS.php"; 
    include "templates/header.php";
    $userId = ASSession::get("user_id");
?>
```

Testing the bio variable return:

```
<?php

    $result = $db->select("SELECT * FROM test WHERE user_id = :id", array( 'id' => $userId )); 
    echo $result['bio'];
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show?

Comment: My guess is there is an exception that is not shown that happens before the echo is reached... Show all errors by error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Are you sure that `select` is a correct method?

Comment: var dump shows: array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["interests"]=> string(0) "" ["bio"]=> string(18) "This is my bio"

Comment: Yes, the documentation for this script uses select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing the array properly, should be

```
echo $result[0]['bio'];
```

because your dump shows an array of array `array(1) { [0]=> array(3) {`

Comment: that's the one, why didn't I spot that.

Comment: Beat me to both the post and the edit by a matter of seconds ;~p

Comment: That did it! And yes, you just beat Daryl. Is there a way to rewrite it so I don't always have to echo result[0] along with [bio]? Most code I see there is no need to echo [0]. I guess this is always necessary when returning an array to get the correct order of field value though?

Comment: @user5000 you seem to have a custom function , I don't know what it is returning, if this is PDO, use `fetch()` instead of `fetchAll()`

Comment: @user5000 I think you should be looking to fetch an associative array, a simple change in the core mechanics of the script (i cannot say i've seen the select method), so look into the class and try to adjust it to fetch();

Comment: Got it. So because I am querying two different tables (users for user ID) and the test (for the bio for that user), my array sql approach makes sense and is why I need to access an array within an array...

Comment: @user5000 basically if you use fetchAll its going to assume you are getting multiple rows so will put it into an array of array, since you get only one row its the first index which is `0`, solution is to use `fetch()` in a different function for instance `select_single()`

Answer (score 1):

The array you have given in the comments for vardump will look like this:

```
array(
    array(
        "user_id" => 2,
        "interests"=>"",
        "bio" => "This is my bio"
    )
);
```

so you are trying to echo a key which is non existent in the first dimension of the array. Try the following:

```
echo $result[0]['bio'];
```

Comment: That was a good answer. I already approved Meda's though. Can I approve two?

Comment: And wouldn't result[0] be referring to the first item in the array (user_id)? I would have thought I would need result[2] to get the bio but obviously not

Comment: @user5000 Only 1 answer per question, but in terms of that comment. You would be referring to the first item in the array, as there are two arrays present. You are essentially telling PHP: *I want to go into this array and then this array and fetch this keys value* with using [0]['bio']. If the array was only a single dimension then yet, using ['bio'] without the [0] would work